# (C#) download embedded flash from a given URL

Tags: c#

I have a desktop forms application . I want to fetch any flash file embedded from a given html page. I used this approach: parse the html page(using htmlagilitypack) to get hold of direct url of any embedded flash, then fetch the file. But this approach wouldn't work if relative paths are used.
How else can a flash file embedded in an html page be downloaded ?

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the domain and the base path from URL you are fetching from. Surely [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) can do the rest?

Comment: i guess first I'll have to figure out, if the flash's path is absolute or relative, then if required combine the paths...

Comment: An absolute path will have a `://` in it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the absolute path.